# Freezing browser DOM state to inspect event based elements?

Tags: javascript, firefox

How do you freeze the DOM state in a browser (e.g. Firefox) so you can inspect elements created from mouse clicks or onhover events?

I'm trying to debug a problem with a Javascript-generated fancy dropdown widget. I want to inspect the markup generated for the expanded "dropdown" after the user clicks the main fake select widget. However, even though I can bring up Firefox's inspection tool for the markup, the moment I click on anything in the inspector tool triggers a blur event that then destroys the generated markup.

Sometimes, even the act of right-clicking to bring up the inspection tool will trigger an event that destroys the DOM element I want to inspect.

How do I make Firefox temporarily halt execution of certain events when the inspection tool is active, so I can actually inspect the DOM?

Comment: If there is somewhere in your code you can pinpoint, you can place a `debugger;` command, and this will cause the debugger to pause there.

Comment: Another option is just place a breakpoint in the code your trying to debug.

Comment: If you know, where your element is supposed to spawn, right click on parent element -> break on -> subtree modifications.